# Error when checking for inequality and retrieving sharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, conditional-statements

I was having an issue in my code where I have four values in a fragment, I need to check if at least one has a value other than zero. I have done this by creating a method `isEmpty()`. In this method, if at least one of the four values - or two or three etc - is a number greater than zero then I retrieve previously set shared preferences, otherwise, all values are reset to zero.

When I use this method is called, the app force closes. Here is the method:

```
// All are values are integers, with the exception of counterMeanRepTimeRefined, which is a Float
public void isEmpty() {
    if (counterNoSets != 0 || counterRepsPerSet != 0
            || counterMeanRepTimeRefined != 0F || counterSetInterval != 0) {
        getSharedPreferenceCounter();
    } else {
        // Resets all of the four values
        counterReset();
    }
}
```

I cannot determine the cause of the problem, however, believe the error is caused by the if-statement in isEmpty(), specifically checking for inequality, retrieving the preferences still works when I remove this method. Here's logcat:

```
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773): Process: com.crackedporcelain.repsetcount, PID: 11773
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:   "Couldn't load saved preference!"
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at    com.crackedporcelain.repsetcount.CreateFragment.getSharedPreferenceCounter(CreateFragment.java:674)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at com.crackedporcelain.repsetcount.CreateFragment.isEmpty(CreateFragment.java:1101)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at com.crackedporcelain.repsetcount.CreateFragment.onClick(CreateFragment.java:1181)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-25 22:17:40.464: E/AndroidRuntime(11773):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken you seem to try parsing string "Couldn't load saved preference!" to int within getSharedPreferenceCounter method (line 674 on CreateFragment.java).

Comment: if it's of any assistance, here is where "Couldn't load saved preference" refers to: `String getSharedPrefCounterNoSets2 = exerciseFolio2.getString("PCNS", "Couldn't load saved preference!");` and line 674: `counterNoSets = Integer.parseInt(getSharedPrefCounterNoSets2);` @harism

Comment: @Rossw19 Seems pretty obvious, no? The error says "Invalid int: "Couldn't load saved preferences"". You're requesting a string from shared preferences with a default value that is not an integer. You're then converting that to an integer. And failing.

Comment: I partially understand what you're saying, but having trouble putting it into practice, I crammed around 400 lines of similar code in my fragment without formatting and commenting it correctly a few days ago. I'm now trying to sieve through it. I've setup a string which coverts an int to a string, it is then saved as a string. I then retrieve the string, and finally convert back into an integer. (The first value before converted to a string is an int, and in the end I try to convert back to an int?) I feel like an idiot that I can't find the simple solution. @kcoppock

Comment: Whoops, just realized I never posted the full stack trace, put the rest there now.

Comment: Again, read the error message. You're calling `Integer.parseInt()` with the value "Couldn't load saved preference!". That is *not* an integer, therefore, exception. This means exerciseFolio2 did not contain a string with the key "PCNS".